# Questions about digital "life" after death

Tags: discussion

I have a series of questions revolving around the central idea of what happens with or what to do with ones digital assets after death. These questions are much broader than Web Apps, however with today's predeliciton of putting everything in the cloud it seems to me this is the closest-to-fitting shoe-that-doesn't-fit.

I could break the questions into categories and fire *"what to do with securing identity after death?"* and *"digital safety deposit boxes: do they exist? are they trustworthy?"* off to [Security.se](http://security.stackexchange.com) and *"how to maintain {blog, flickr, facebook...} for posterity?"* to [WebApps.se](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/) and *"how to ensure my family gets personal docs from my work machine"* to [SuperUser.se](https://superuser.com/) and *"small non-profit: sysadmin died, now what?"* to [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/). It would be nice to have them available as a collection though. What do you think? is this the best site to start? or maybe I should look to someplace outside the Stack Exchange network?

Comment: great idea, at any rate

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Someone's already gone and died for you for a start, "[What happens to your Facebook account when you die?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/11436/what-happens-to-your-facebook-account-when-you-die)".

It would be interesting as a series of blog posts. Maybe you can float the idea as a run on [the Super User blog](http://blog.superuser.com/contribute/).

You could also do as suggested and ask those questions across the various sites. Then collect and summarise them on your own site or blog as a hub of "Kicking the virtual bucket when you take a nap six feet under".

Comment: ok, I've started asking across the sites. We'll see how this develops. (and to everyone, please feel free add your own questions and/or to collect and summarise on your own site, etc. I feel no ownership of the theme, and it may take me a long time to follow through to the end [pun intended].)